# Динамическое обновление контента в WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

Задача заключается в следующем, нужно заставить `WebView` отображать страницу после изменения её содержимого сервером. Например, когда на странице есть разворачивающийся список (реализованный с помощью `js` на стороне сервера), то при клике на него никаких действий не происходит, когда в обычном браузере список становится активным (разворачивается) и мы уже можем взаимодействовать с его элементами. Нужно это для того, чтобы парсить добавленные сервером на страницу элементы

`WebView` вызывается следующим образом:

```
webview = new WebView();
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
webview.setWebViewClient(wc);
webview.setWebChromeClient(wvc);
webview.loadUrl("http://klavogonki.ru/gamelist");
```

Список игр на сайте не прогружается.

Comment: код покажите, как загружаете страницу в `WebView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меня заинтересовал Ваш случай - действительно не все просто. Держите рабочий код (он не оптимален - подправьте), работоспособность я проверял на API17:

myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

webSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

myWebView.loadUrl("http://klavogonki.ru/gamelist");
```

В mainifest в секции application Добавьте android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, вроде бы всё работает. Сейчас не могу точно всё проверить, так как на сервер совершается атака (кто-то создает множество клиентов и захотит в игры, тем самым перегружая сервер и список не обновляется, возможно дело ещё и в слобом интернете). Как только атака прекратится я проверю ваш код ещё раз и попробую парсить данные. А пока почитаю про те методы которыми вы настраивали `WebView`. Очень выручили.

Comment: Да, всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас в WebView выключенJS (по умолчанию он выключен). Далее привожу код для корректного отображения WEB страниц

```
//где myWebView - Ваша WebView
final WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   //ВОТ ВКЛЮЧЕНИЕ JS!!!
            String userAgent = "Chrome/26.0.1410.58";
            webSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://mail.ru/");
```

Comment: Не сработало. У меня, разумеется, эта функция включена, ведь я по средствам `js` получаю данные с сервера. я добвлю в вопрос то, как я вызываю `WebView`.